# perl: Use of uninitialized value $file in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl

The error occurs in a custom perl module for reading in a file. This uses CGI so the error messages get displayed in the browser.

```
my $check = CreateExam->new("exam2.txt","grades.txt");
$check->readexam();
```

CreateExam.pm:

```
sub new {
    my ($class,$file,$grades) = @_;
    print "<p>in new: file: $file, grades: $grades</p>\n";
    return bless {'file'=>$file,'gradefile'=>$grades},$class;
}

sub readexam {
    my $self = shift;
    print "<p>in readexam File: $self->{'file'}</p>\n";
    if (defined($self->{'file'})) {
        my $self->{'questions'} = [];
        my $count = -1;
        my $file = $self->{'file'};
        open(my $handle,"<$file") or die "<p>it was the open. File: $file</p>";
        while(<$handle>) {
```

ouput:

```
in new: file: exam2.txt, grades: grades.txt

in readexam File: exam2.txt

Use of uninitialized value $file in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/homeworks/hw10/CreateExam.pm line 35 (#1)

Software error:

<p>it was the open. File: </p> at /var/www/homeworks/hw10/CreateExam.pm line 35.

Software error:

[Sun Dec 21 14:30:31 2014] hw10.cgi: <p>it was the open. File: </p> at /var/www/homeworks/hw10/CreateExam.pm line 

[Sun Dec 21 14:30:31 2014] hw10.cgi: [Sun Dec 21 14:30:31 2014] hw10.cgi:
it was the open. File:

at /var/www/homeworks/hw10/CreateExam.pm line 35.
```

I had `use warnings` and `use diagnostics`. It seems strange that I get a part of the error message twice.

Comment: I don't think you posted all of `CreateExam.pm` - specifically did you post line 35?

Comment: `my $self->{'questions'} = [];` - what's that supposed to mean? why not just `$self->{questions} = [];`?

Comment: @raina77ow: *“what's that supposed to mean?”* It's clearly a mistake, and your comment isn't constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a new variable `$self` at this point in your code:

```
    my $self->{'questions'} = [];
    my $count = -1;
    my $file = $self->{'file'};
```

Then you try to access it and assign a value to another variable `$file`, which will become undefined. When you use `my` you create a new variable in the current scope.

So the answer is probably: Don't use `my` in this case. You have already used it once at the top of the sub.

However...

It is completely redundant to assign a new array ref to the key `questions`. Perl's autovivification can handle that, e.g. if you do `push @{ $self->{questions} }, $foo`, you will create an array ref.